# Работа с массивами в ассемблер

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

помогите, пожалуйста разобраться в коде. Не могу понять вставку на ассемблере. Не могли бы Вы прокомментировать каждую строчку. Буду Вам очень благодарна.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char C, x[3], * y;
    short i;
    y = new char[4];
    C = '0';
    cout << "y[4]= ";
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        y[i] = C;
        cout << y[i] << " ";
        C++;
    }
    C = 'A';
    cout << endl << "x[3]= ";
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        x[i] = C;
        cout << x[i] << " ";
        C++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    _asm
    {
        MOV AL, 0
        MOV EBX, y
        XLAT // выбирается элемент
        MOV DL, x[0]
        MOV x[0], AL
        MOV[EBX], DL

        MOV AL, 1
        XLAT
        inc EBX
        MOV DL, x[1]
        MOV x[1], AL
        MOV[EBX], DL

        MOV AL, 1
        XLAT
        inc EBX
        MOV DL, x[2]
        MOV x[2], AL
        MOV[EBX], DL
    }
    cout << endl << "y[4]= ";
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout << y[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << "x[3]= ";
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    delete[] y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: это с++ со вставкой на ассемблере

Comment: Извиняюсь, не увидел